# Different functions or single assignable property with side effects?

Tags: c++, c++14, api-design, gui-toolkit

I'm designing/writing a small UI toolkit (for self-betterment purposes, what else?) and I am unsure what kind of API would be better in the following senses:

1. lowest WTF? level.
2. most flexible.
3. most succinct, yet descriptive
4. best fit with Standard C++.

Some elements that are important:

- The `window` class represents well, a window, and can be shown, hidden, minimized, maximized, full screen maximized, and closed.
- I have a `proxy_property` class which can be assigned arbitrary get and set functions that can e.g. reflect a current value that ought to be fetched or set through some external API call.
- I also have a `property` class that can be connected to (i.e. observed), and when it is assigned a new/different value, will signal this new value to its observers.

I am unsure what the best way to handle the window state:

1. Private member variable, only accessible through `hide()`, `isVisible()` etc. member functions, Qt style.
2. read-only property (will need some extra implementation as I don't currently have this worked out) that is backed by `hide()`, `show()`, etc. getters and updated accordingly.
3. A `proxy_property` that can be assigned a new state, resulting in a call to `hide()`, `show()`, etc. or a combination thereof when assigned a new value.

At first glance, I'd prefer number 3 for reason 3, but in light of the other conditions I'm unsure how well this design will hold up. Suffice to say I haven't seen my number 3 used anywhere, and I'm afraid to lean too much on my `proxy_property` concept as it might incur more overhead than it's worth (on the other hand, this is UI code we're talking about, so overhead will be there nonetheless).

For clarity:

```
enum class window_state { windowed, hidden, minimized, maximized, fullscreen_maximized };
class window
{
public:
  proxy_property<window_state> state;
  //....
};
```

So one can do

```
some_window.state = window_state::minimized;
```

To actually do something more traditionally done by e.g.

```
some_window.minimize();
```

The end result would be functionally identical of course. It's just the API that is completely different.

Comment: Just do this `some_window.state = window_state::minimized;` inside `some_window.minimize()`. Calling `some_window.minimize();` is much better for the user.

Comment: Ummm ain't that a bit overboard with broadness and opinion influence? I don't think there exists a clear-cut approach for design decisions you present.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be careful to distinguish between the properties you can set (e.g., say, `visibility` from the properties you can observe (e.g. `isVisible`), because in many cases the observable properties depend on more than just the setting.

A control, for example `isVisible` if it has `visibility == true` AND it's container `isVisible`.

There is no reason to make a control's `visibility` setting observable, and it fact it would probably lead to mistakes.

For this reason, I would prefer setters and getters for `visibility`, and a listenable property for `isVisible`.